# Make button turn visible when variable reaches certain value

Tags: variables, jbutton, return-value

I would like to know how you can make it so that a button turns visible as soons as a variable hits a certain value.
it should be like an upgrade in a minigame, so that youre only able to click it when you have enough gold.

This is the button:

```
upgrade1 = new JButton("-50");
    upgrade1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pickaxe.png")));
    upgrade1.setBorderPainted(false);
    upgrade1.setFocusPainted(false);
    upgrade1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    upgrade1.setBounds(200, 200, 150, 150);
```

this is its action listener:

```
upgrade1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
     {
         klicks -= 50;
         test.setText("Gold:" + " " + klicks);
         k = 2;
     }

});
```

This is the "Currency":

```
public int klicks=0;
```

Its put to zero because the player starts with 0 gold

Comment: Please add the code of the button and the variable you want to check.

Comment: Do you need more code or is that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On instanciation of the `upgrade1` button, make it invisible `upgrade1.setVisible(false);`.

Put the following code where you add gold to the user:

```
if (klicks >= 50) {
    upgrade1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Make sure to set the button invisible if the gold drops below `50`, for example if the user buys another item. Set it to invisible after the user has bought the upgrade as well.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible(boolean)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but where do i add the code you posted?
In the buttons Action Listener, at the variable?

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the answer by the way :D

Comment: You are welcome. Please uovote and accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: You add the code where the player gains points. That is dependent on your code. The first line you can add after your first code block